# “missing required :bucket option” for Paperclip/S3/Ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I tried adding the editor to my rails app using amazons3 and paperclip but im having errors. If I cant get this to work, what other editors are available that would work? Here is the error I got below

```
ArgumentError in Ckeditor::PicturesController#create
missing required :bucket option

Extracted source (around line #218):
216
217
218
219
220
221

        @bucket = @options[:bucket] || s3_credentials[:bucket]
        @bucket = @bucket.call(self) if @bucket.respond_to?(:call)
        @bucket or raise ArgumentError, "missing required :bucket option"
      end

      def s3_interface
```

I'm not sure what to do as I followed these steps.

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'ckeditor'
```

then bundled

```
rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip
```

rake migrated

```
mount Ckeditor::Engine => "/ckeditor"
```

added this to application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

added this to the view page

```
    <%= f.cktext_area :content, :class => "form-control" %>
```

---

These are the files created and their configuration

**/Ckeditor/Picture.rb**

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
                    :url  => ":s3_domain_url",
                    :path =>         "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
                    :styles => { :content => '800>', :thumb => '118x100#' }

  validates_attachment_presence :data
  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :data, :content_type => /\Aimage/

  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end
end
```

**/Ckeditor/attachment_file.rb**

```
  class Ckeditor::AttachmentFile < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
                    :url => "/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename"

  validates_attachment_presence :data
  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 100.megabytes
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :data

  def url_thumb
    @url_thumb ||= Ckeditor::Utils.filethumb(filename)
  end
end
```

**/Ckeditor/asset.rb**

```
class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase
  include Ckeditor::Backend::Paperclip
end
```

---

I use these lines of code in `development.rb` and `production.rb` and I haven't had any issues with paperclip before with s3.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_protocol => 'http',
:bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
:s3_credentials => {
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
    }
```

This is the `paperclip.rb` file

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are deploying in heroku. So you need to set heroku environment variable for s3 bucket variable:

```
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME='Your Bucket Name'
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='Your AWS ID'
heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='Your AWS Secrete Key'
```

If you are in development(local) you need to define this variables. Otherwise remove config code from development.rb

Comment: I didn't use that, but I got it to work using different method. Problem is that the images are uploaded, I've verified, but its not showing

Comment: Just once. But if you are in development enviroment probably you lost variables when you reboot machine. For test try  to replace ENV with your credentials.( just for test, is not a security recommended practice)

Comment: Are you testing in heroku or local?

Comment: local for now, I've gotten it to upload but im having issues with displaying the images once uploaded in the app

Comment: How you tell to your  application which are your amazon credentials?

Comment: That is the error you have. The app dont know the AWS_BUCKET

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It uploaded it to the bucket, what do you mean it doesn't know?

Comment: I am just telling what the error means and how to check. In theory you could not upload neither. But that is all I  can tell  from my position .

Comment: Oh. I don't know, I'm still somewhat confused. So if it is uploading an image, I can verify it, yet it wont show the upload. That means its confused about the AWS_BUCKET. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't have a PicturesController, I do have a pictures.rb file. I updated the code to allow it to upload to amazon, but It wont show the image. Do you mean that code? I can update that if you like

Comment: The error comes from PicturesController#create. You have it

Comment: I don't have it, I think it came with the ckeditor code, but its not there. I'm not sure why its referencing it, but I did a search and only came up with the development log. There's no PicturesController, but there is a Pictures.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81918/discussion-between-jamesrocky-and-papayalabs).